# Why do my Borland C++Builder 5 forms with right-anchored controls appear incorrectly on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, anchor, c++builder, vcl

Having spent a small age looking for the solution and having now found it, I figured this would be good to document for Stack Overflow.  So my answer will follow right after this question.

I was using Borland C++ Builder 5.  This probably also applies to the equivalent version of Delphi.  I had a form with a TButton on a TPanel.  The button was set to akRight,akBottom. On XP and prior Windows, everything was fine.  On Vista, using Aero, the button appeared 4 pixels too far to the right.  The anchoring continued to work fine.

Another example was a form with a TComboBox which had akTop,akRight,akLeft.  The combo appeared 4 pixels too wide on Vista.

Returning to the "classic" look on Vista made everything appear correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I tried didn't work: I guessed that the problem had to do with the wider window borders on Vista.  I figured UpdateAnchorRules in VCL was somehow calculating incorrectly due to the difference between the design width and the actual width of the window on Vista.  Looking at the VCL source, it was clear that changing the anchors would cause UpdateAnchorRules to be called again and (hopefully) calculate correctly, since it now had the actual width of the form available.

I added

```
TAnchors t = BlahBtn->Anchors;
t >> akRight;
BlahBtn->Anchors = t;
t << akRight;
BlahBtn->Anchors = t;
```

to my form's constructor.

No joy.  The behaviour was entirely unaffected.

I figured this might be too early in the process, so moved the same code to the FormShow method, equally unsuccessfully.  As a last try, I changed the design of the form to no longer have akRight for the button and changed the code to

```
TAnchors t = BlahBtn->Anchors;
t << akRight;
BlahBtn->Anchors = t;
```

...which failed too - behaviour entirely unaffected, other than that I broke the positioning of the button on XP in the case that the saved size of the form (which I read out of the registry and apply to the form in FormShow) wasn't the default.

Having added a metric tonne of debug code outputting the width of the form, width of the button, left of the button, ClientRect of the form, etc. at various points during the form's lifetime, I found the problem.  For some reason (presumably still window-border-related - I didn't manage to find out exactly what the reason was), VCL was opening the window with the width 4 pixels below what it should have been.  The width got corrected shortly thereafter, but by that point, the anchoring (and UpdateAnchorRules) had already fixed the positioning of the button 4 pixels too far to the right.

The fix was:

```
void __fastcall TFooBarDlg::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
{
    TForm::CreateParams(Params);
    int i = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
    Params.Width=Params.Width+(2*(i-4));
}
```

This corrects the initial width of the form, using the differing size of the border as reported by Vista.  It causes the correct behaviour on Vista while retaining it on other Windows versions (and Vista with "classic" look).

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I have a vague memory (possibly incorrect) that older versions of Delphi stored only the form's width and height.  That means that the form could be recreated the wrong size when run on Windows with different window frame settings - and that includes customised versions of 2000/XP, because you can change that in the display settings.  Newer editions of Delphi stream the ClientWidth and ClientHeight (size inside the window frame), removing this problem.  Looks like you found a solution!  But the most robust solution is upgrading to a newer version... D5 is, what, ten-to-twelve years old?

Comment: BCB5 is from 2000, D5 is from 1999, so yeah, they're ancient. The question's also not new, though - I posted in 2009.  Shortly after that, we made the move to BCB2009 and since then to XE3.  BCB5 did have one "advantage" vs. the versions then available: it was able to produce Win9x-compatible binaries.  At the time, our app would therefore run on anything Win95+.  You'd think no-one would care, but when we released the first BCB2009 version (compatible with Win2k+), we did actually get a couple of complaints from people still using WinME...