# Odd behaviour with components with akRight alignment

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-vista, delphi-7

In one customer computer (windows vista) almost all forms of my app are oddly unnaligned.

Making some investigation I noticed that every component with akRight anchor acts oddly, being positioned way more for the right.

Searching in SO I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355258/delphi-7-forms-anchors-not-working-in-vista) issue wich is similar to mine but not exacly the same.

Since I cannot reproduce the issue in my computer and my access to my customer´s computer is restrict to a few minutes and via remote desktop I´d like to know if my issue described here could be solved by the same fix.

Comment: Why don't you apply the same fix to your program, and then spend "a few minutes" to see whether it works? Does it really take longer than that to see whether the problem is still there?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I didn´t make myself clear. That few minutes are restricted. Maybe I´ll have access to my customer computer in 2 or 3 days. Until there I am trying to increase the chances to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you experiencing the problem described in the following question?

[Why do my Borland C++Builder 5 forms with right-anchored controls appear incorrectly on Vista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525517/why-do-my-borland-cbuilder-5-forms-with-right-anchored-controls-appear-incorrec)

Maybe the answer is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced similar issues. After much frustration I pretty much gave up using anchors and started using a combination of the Align, AlignWithMargins and Margins properties.

Comment: Could you, please, write more about your solution?